# Check if a gridView is empty

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-10-universal

I want to know if my gridView is empty-doesn't have any items in it.
I have tried to do the following :

```
public sealed partial class Profile : Page
{
    Boolean isGridViewEmpty = true;       
}
```

This is the function that shows the grid view, and I have tried to make it also determine whether or not the gridview is empty

```
//gets the animals of the specific chosen user's data tabe
    public async void getAnimalsData(int ownerId)
    {
        int count = 0;
        regitration.getAnimalsOfUserTableResponseGetAnimalsOfUserTableResult r = await cal.getAnimalsOfUserTableAsync(ownerId);
        List<Animal> theAnimalList = new List<Animal>();
        Animal a = null;
        XmlReader xr = r.Any1.CreateReader();
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(xr);
        XmlNodeList theXmlList = document.GetElementsByTagName("Table");
        foreach (XmlElement item in theXmlList)
        {
            a = new Animal();
            foreach (XmlNode node in item.ChildNodes)
            {
                switch (node.Name)
                {
                    case "animalId": a.AnimalId = int.Parse(node.InnerText); count++; break;
                    case "ownerId": a.OwnerId = int.Parse(node.InnerText); count++; break;
                    case "animalName": a.Animalname = node.InnerText; count++; break;
                    case "fur": a.Fur = node.InnerText; count++; break;
                    case "level": a.Level = int.Parse(node.InnerText); count++; break;
                    case "money": a.Money = int.Parse(node.InnerText); count++; break;
                }
            }
            theAnimalList.Add(a);
        }
        grid2.ItemsSource = theAnimalList;
        if (count == 0)
        {
            isGridViewEmpty = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isGridViewEmpty = false;
        }

    }
```

Upon debugging, I could see that it doesn't really exit the function, although, it also doesn't display an error message. It just appears stuck after the last curly bracket. 
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, the count appears to work fine , upon debugging it also shows me that `isGridViewEmpty` is really set to true, but whenever I come to implement the function and I check if `isGridViewEmpty`is true, it doesn't work. Also, as I mentioned before, the debugger gets stuck in the function `getAnimalsData`

Comment: Are there any exceptions? Deadlocks? How are you calling this method?

Comment: There aren't any exceptions, and I even tried if (grid2.Items.Count==0)         
                {
                    noAnimalsProtocol();
                } However, it is as if the program executes the getAnimalsData()  last, no matter where I put it in code

Comment: For your description, you need to check the if `getAnimalsOfUserTableAsync` method has invoked correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the problem, the function getAnimalsData was async so it actually did work it's just that it happened in the background and not in the order that I put it, and so whenever I had conditions relating that function it would appear as though it didn't work, so I made it a task instead of void and put  await before the function.

Comment: Create, may I converter this comment to an answer for this case?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The function `getAnimalsData` was `async`. So it actually works, just because it happens in the background instead of the order I pressed it, so whenever I have conditional related functionality, it looks useless. So I made it a [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=netcore-2.2) instead of `void` and put `await` before the function.

For more detail you could refer [Asynchronous programming with async and await (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).